# Sheet name in excel

Tags: jxls

Is there any way to set sheet name using JxlsHelper to fill excel template?

```
Context context = new Context();
context.putVar("data", hereIsListOfData());
InputStream templateStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(EXCEL_TEMPLATE);
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream());
JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(templateStream, output, context);
```

Answer (score 1):

Achieved thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40789235/7913021

```
Context context = new Context();
context.putVar("data", hereIsListOfData());

InputStream templateStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(EXCEL_TEMPLATE);
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream());

Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(templateStream);
workbook.setSheetName(0, sheetName);

PoiTransformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createTransformer(workbook);
transformer.setOutputStream(output);

JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(context, transformer);
```